# How to reload sinatra modular application mounted into Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra

I've mounted Sinatra application using Rails 3 mount routing:

```
mount Api2.new, :at => "/api2"
```

I want all changes to sinatra application to be reloaded on each requst in development environment.

How could I achieve that?

I've tried [sinatra contrib reloader](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra-contrib/issues/29), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [shotgun](http://ruby.about.com/od/sinatra/a/sinatra5.htm)? And what exactly happens when you use sinatra/reloader? I noticed that depending on the type of change, I must restart the app for the changes to take effect, although it uses sinatra/reloader